# Is it possible to define package procedure/function outside of package body block (for Oracle)?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, syntax

Is it possible to define package procedure/function outside of package body block (for Oracle)?

Simplified syntax for [defining package body](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_pc.htm) is:

```
create or replace package body <package_name> IS

  function <function_name>
   <function_body>

  procedure <procedure_name>
   <procedure_body>

end <package_name>;
/
```

Is it possible to define procedure within package like:

```
procedure <package_name>.<procedure_name>
 <procedure_body>
```

I ask this question as I am newbie and don't understand why I need to compile  whole package when I need only to apply changes form a single procedure...

**RELATED**

- [What are the benefits of packages over standalone procedures and functions?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7768/what-are-the-benefits-of-packages-over-standalone-procedures-and-functions)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812049/performance-standalone-procedure-vs-packaged-procedure-in-oracle

Tom [says](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:7452431376537):

- Always use a package.
- Never use a standalone procedure except for demos, tests and standalone utilities (that call nothing and are called by nothing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You always need to compile the entire package body -- it is one item of code. You can create functions and procedures inside other procedures, but that does not change the need to recompile the package body.

What problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: Thanks for answer.+1 As I say in question I am in situation when I have to apply fix to procedure from package. For newbie it is unclear that I must apply whole package in order to integrate small bug fix to part of package....

Comment: Yes, that's the case I'm afraid. Just recompile the package body though, not the package, unless the interface with any of the procedures or functions has changed. The package body is separated from the package so that recompilation of the body does not cause invalidation of other objects.

Comment: Thanks again! I had another question about recompilation of package **header** vs **body** and you answered it in comment!!

Comment: Ah, well remember that when you're deploying code the best approach is to deploy all of the packages and then deploy the package bodies. You won't have to think about which order to deploy the individual packages in.

Answer (score 0):

Not there.  But your idea is a good one....

In Ada, which was the origin of PL/SQL, you could define a part of a package body, like a procedure, as ["separate"](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12aarm/html/AA-10-1-3.html#S0258).

This would allow you to break up overly long package bodies (in Ada) without losing the internal variables etc.

Definitely would love to see it in PL/SQL.